# Creating a user with read permissions to all directories in a Linux server

Tags: permissions, ftp

I need to connect to a remote Linux server over SFTP and read the entire folder structure of the server. I would like to list all directories, even directories with no read permissions, and preferably without changing the permissions of the directories.

I would like to avoid using root, and I think that a good solution could be to create a "read only" root. When searching for a solution online, I found the `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` capability. However, capabilities require me to specify a filename, and I don't think I would like the capability to apply to the SSHD process.

How can I create a user with the needed permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
sftpsrv=/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
cp -a ${sftpsrv} ${sftpsrv}.super
chmod 500 ${sftpsrv}.super
chown someuser ${sftpsrv}.super
/sbin/setcap cap_dac_read_search+ep ${sftpsrv}.super
```

You'll need to connect to your server this way:

`sftp -s /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server.super address`

And it works!

```bsh
ls -la /tmp | grep TEST
drwx------.  2 root   root       60 Oct 29 13:08 TEST

sftp -s /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server.super localhost
user@localhost^s password: 
Connected to localhost.
sftp> cd /tmp/TEST
sftp> ls
123
```

`/tmp/TEST` is owned by root and has `700` permissions.

---

Here's a possible untested solution in case your client is unable to request a custom sftp-server binary:

```
Match User someuser
    Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server.super
```

Comment: That's a very interesting approach, however I don't think that the new ls will be used when connecting through SFTP

Comment: @ben

I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sounds promising. let me make sure I understand. You basically created a new instance of sftp, which only "someuser" has the ability to use, and granted it the capability. "someuser" is not a superuser at all. I will try it out.

Comment: Exactly like that. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the way you suggested I duplicate the sftp-server.
With the library that I currently use, I don't have the option to specify the location of sftp-server when connecting to the server. but I guess I can look into creating a new sftp daemon that listens to a different port. 
I really Appreciate you help!

Comment: `sftp-server` doesn't listen to anything, it's what `sshd` does. Upon connecting your client asks the server to run the `sftp-server` binary instead of a shell.

Comment: Okay, so I think that I need to create another sshd, with it's sftp subsystem pointing to sftp-server.super. Would you say that's a reasonable solution?

Comment: Updated the answer once again

Comment: Subsystem is not allowed under Match User, however I think I succeeded using ForceCommand = /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server.super. Thank you.